# Dropouts in AWD-LSTM

Tags: neural-network, lstm, fast-ai, dropout

I am trying to implement AWD-LSTM and thus would like to ensure I understand the dropout techniques correctly. I have read the article & fastai docs but still doubt whether I have understood it properly.

Embedding dropout (embed_p) - probability of substituting the word embedding with zero vector.

Input dropout (input_p) - probability of substituting each component of the chosen embedding vector with 0.

Weight dropout (weight_p) - probability of substituting each weight for all the recurrent matrices with 0.

Hidden (recurrent) Dropout (hidden_p) - probability of substituting each component of the update-vector (obtained after multiplying the result of tanh layer with input gate layer output.

The names are received from [here](https://dev.fast.ai/text.models.awdlstm).

Have I given the correct definitions to all the kinds of dropouts?

Comment: Could you clarify the question?

Comment: Certainly. Have I given the correct definitions to all the kinds of dropouts?

Comment: stackoverflow is about practical software problems/algorithms. "have i given the correct definitions" isn't a good question for this forum. Consider to include a piece of code, error, expected result, specific problem, etc. And people will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: But I need to implement the formulaes. I believe there is no difference I will ask for the correct definition or I will adduce my implementation and wonder whether it is done truly.